# They made their wishes watching the sunrise

Tags: grammar

1. They made their wishes watching the sunrise.
2. They made their wishes watching sunrise.

---

Which one is correct? Do we have to put 'the' before 'sunrise' or not?

Comment: Do you mean "They made their wishes (come true) watching the sunrise."? We usually don't "make wishes" in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. "They made their wishes watching the sunrise."

is correct.  Also correct:

> They made their wishes watching a beautiful winter sunrise.

Also correct, with a slightly different parsing:

> They made their wishes watching the sun rise.

Incorrect: the version without an article.